# Is there a character that is illegal in all parts of a URI?

Tags: url, uri, split, illegal-characters

I need a character to separate two or more URIs in one string. Later I will the split the string to get each URI separately.

The problem is I'm not sure what character to pick here. Is there a good character to choose here that definitely can't be part of a URI itself? Or is ultimately pretty much all characters allowed in a URI?

I know certain characters are illegal in certain parts of the URI, but I'm talking about a URI as a whole, like this:

```
scheme://username:password@domain.tld/path/to/file.ext?key=value#blah
```

I'm thinking maybe `space`, although technically I suppose that could be part of the password, or would it be escaped as `%20` in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of the control characters should be good for this, such as TAB, FF and so on.

RFC3986 <sup>(a)</sup> controls the URI specification and [Appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) of that RFC states that the characters are limited to:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=
```

(and the `%` encoding character, of course, for all other characters not listed above).

So, basically, any other character should be okay as a delimiter.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This has actually been augmented by RFC6874 which has to do with changes to the IPv6 part of the URI, adding a zone identifier. Since the zone ID consists of `%` and "unreserved" characters already included above, it doesn't change the set of characters allowed.

Comment: Using the TAB character sounds like a good idea. Think I'll try that out. If it doesn't work well I'll just use the space character.